# All Cassandra nodes have the same DC and rack but Java driver warns about some contact points are from a different DC

Tags: java, cassandra

We have a Cassandra cluster version `3.11.11` made of 3 nodes, in a same virtual network in Azure.

`nodetool info` reports `datacenter1` is the datacenter for each node:

```
Data Center            : datacenter1
Rack                   : rack1
```

Here is `nodetool status` output:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.22.0.6  171.59 GiB  256          67.2%             7bc5241d-ed74-4ac6-bdcb-cab41b3a2104  rack1
UN  172.22.0.4  170.67 GiB  256          66.4%             6d425e7f-1f04-4d9e-9bc6-47b2b1b7810e  rack1
UN  172.22.0.5  170.75 GiB  256          66.4%             30cce9ef-56a5-47ff-bfde-632dadf068da  rack1
```

And here is the `nodetool gossipinfo` output:

```
/172.22.0.6
  generation:1634048234
  heartbeat:5869658
  STATUS:18:NORMAL,-1125078076903450660
  LOAD:5869634:1.83740260211E11
  SCHEMA:14:45c7f8ec-4e41-394a-9ea2-7a0ef644ec60
  DC:10:datacenter1
  RACK:12:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:5:3.11.11
  INTERNAL_IP:8:172.22.0.6
  RPC_ADDRESS:4:13.94.187.33
  NET_VERSION:2:11
  HOST_ID:3:7bc5241d-ed74-4ac6-bdcb-cab41b3a2104
  RPC_READY:30:true
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:6:big-me,big-md
  TOKENS:17:<hidden>
/172.22.0.4
  generation:1634047421
  heartbeat:5869859
  STATUS:18:NORMAL,-1031235602051957145
  LOAD:5869827:1.82809890792E11
  SCHEMA:14:45c7f8ec-4e41-394a-9ea2-7a0ef644ec60
  DC:10:datacenter1
  RACK:12:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:5:3.11.11
  INTERNAL_IP:8:172.22.0.4
  RPC_ADDRESS:4:52.157.177.58
  NET_VERSION:2:11
  HOST_ID:3:6d425e7f-1f04-4d9e-9bc6-47b2b1b7810e
  RPC_READY:30:true
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:6:big-me,big-md
  TOKENS:17:<hidden>
/172.22.0.5
  generation:1634048028
  heartbeat:5868190
  STATUS:18:NORMAL,-1023554233107573736
  LOAD:5868171:1.82744456298E11
  SCHEMA:14:45c7f8ec-4e41-394a-9ea2-7a0ef644ec60
  DC:10:datacenter1
  RACK:12:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:5:3.11.11
  INTERNAL_IP:8:172.22.0.5
  RPC_ADDRESS:4:13.81.175.208
  NET_VERSION:2:11
  HOST_ID:3:30cce9ef-56a5-47ff-bfde-632dadf068da
  RPC_READY:32:true
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:6:big-me,big-md
  TOKENS:17:<hidden>
```

Yet, we have these warnings below when using Cassandra Java driver.

```
12:23:19.181 [s0-admin-0] WARN  c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper - [s0|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=xxx-node-02.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/xxx:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=18a8031a)=null, Node(endPoint=xxx-node-01.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/xxx:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=424a8b33)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
```

Cassandra driver version is `com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.13.0`.

How to fix them? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the output of `nodetool status`?

Comment: Thanks @wtekiela I've added it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

In the warning message up above:

> hostId=null

That ^ is suspect, to me.  It suggests that there once were nodes in the cluster (which have since been removed) which didn't fully-complete the removal process.  So the dead IPs and some other info are still hanging out in gossip on one or more nodes.

On a few of your good nodes, try running `nodetool gossipinfo` or (via cqlsh) `SELECT peer,host_id,data_center FROm system.peers;`

What you're looking for are nodes/IPs that are not listed in your `nodetool status`.  Remember that gossip is unique for each node in the cluster, so you'll have to check all of them.  Once you find them, `nodetool assassinate` definitely should get rid of them.

```
nodetool assassinate <old_ip_address>
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it looks like no dead IP is listed, I have added the gossip command output in my original post.